# Ros diagnostics aggregator, faster stale

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have noticed that ros diagnostics aggregator report that a node is "stale" after 5s without any diagnostics messages. Is there a way to reduce it to 2 or 3 seconds ?
I think this value should not be hard coded anyway !

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362337/ros-diagnostics-aggregator,-faster-stale/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2020-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question, Using the `timeout` parameter in the configuration of the analyzer works fine :

Example :

```
  sensors:
    type: AnalyzerGroup
    path: Sensors
    analyzers:
      base_hk:
        type: GenericAnalyzer
        path: Base Hokuyo
        timeout: 5.0
        find_and_remove_prefix: base_hokuyo_node
        num_items: 3
      tilt_hk:
        type: GenericAnalyzer
        path: Tilt Hokuyo
        timeout: 5.0
        find_and_remove_prefix: tilt_hokuyo_node
        num_items: 3
      imu:
        type: GenericAnalyzer
        path: IMU
        timeout: 5.0
        find_and_remove_prefix: imu_node
        num_items: 3
```

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2020-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0